# Redirect to checkout after add to cart?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am using Drupal 8. I installed the Drupal commerce module and successfully set it up .

I am able to add the products to the cart, but I want to redirect the users to checkout as soon as the product is added. How can I achieve this?

In Drupal 7 we can do this using rules, but I am not able to find the rule event for this, in Drupal 8.